# Li parent elemnt is not selected on child li selection in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have write code to make the li active on url basis .It works fine but it fails on child li.It make child li active while i want that top li should be active not child.My code is below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function () {
    setNavigation();
});

function setNavigation() {


// this portion code make li active on url basis

    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    path = pathname.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);

    var value = jQuery(location).attr('href');
//   value  = value.replace('.html', ''); alert(value);
    jQuery(".flexy-menu a").each(function () {
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
        if (value === href) { 
            jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });

// this is code for child li but only first code works

    jQuery('.flexy-menu').children('li').click(function(){ 
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    });

}</script>
```

My HTML is like this :

```
<ul class="flexy-menu orange">
            <li style=""><a href="http://example.com/">Home</a></li>
            <li style=""><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Collection</a>
<ul style="">            <li><a href="http://example.com/my-secret-garden.html">My Secret Garden </a></li>
     <li><a href="http://example.com/legend.html">Legend</a></li></ul>
</li>

            <li class="active" style=""><a href="http://example.com/artisans">Artisans</a></li>
            <li style=""><a href="http://example.com/contacts">Contact </a></li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parent use `.closest()`:

```
jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
```

and put this in doc ready:

```
jQuery(function () {
    setNavigation();
    jQuery('.flexy-menu').find('li').click(function(){ 
        jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Here i changed your selector little bit with `.find()` instead of `.children()`, because `.find()` looks for grand child also and if you want to traverse up to the parent then use `.closest()` method.

---

*I have write code to make the li active on url basis*

Okay! then you can choose to do this:

```
$('a[href*="'+ path +'"]').parents('li').addClass('active');
```

---

### This should work:

All to all you just need to do this only, no extra function required:

```
jQuery(function () {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    $('a[href*="'+ path +'"]').parents('li').addClass('active');
    jQuery('.flexy-menu').find('li').click(function(){ 
        jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but not working.still selecting child li and make it active.

Comment: One i thing i forget to mention that page loads after each click.So i think click event not works here.We have to check on url basis.

Comment: @Adda would you tell us what is `jQuery(location)` in your case.

Comment: @Adda this should work `$('a[href*="'+ path +'"]').parents('li').addClass('active');` you don't need a loop for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.flexy-menu > li').click(function(e){    
jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hqPQu/

Comment: Thanks One thing i forget to mention that page loads after each click.So i think click event not works here.I have to check on url basis like for parent i did.